# Проблема c установкой интерпретатора в pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

При попытке установить интерпретатор вылезает следующая ошибка:

> ```
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\\Users\\***\\venv'
> ```

Я создал проект в PyCharm, до этого я полностью удалял Python и PyCharm с моего компьютера, далее зашёл в Settings, Projects, нажал Python interpreter, show all, нажал +, и нажал OK. После чего он выдал ошибку

> ```
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\\Users\\***\\venv'
> ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)